# Scroll marquee till last character in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

How to add scroll delay in this coding for marquee ?

It will not scroll till the last character, it will disappear when first character in literal1 will touch the left side ...

i want it will scroll till last ..character

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim example As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim str As String = "<img src=a.gif/>"
        Dim resulte As String = "<MARQUEE>" & str & " " & example & "</MARQUEE>"
        Literal1.Text = resulte
    End Sub
```

Comment: Which browser are you using to view this in? I think Marquee can have some unexpected behaviours so that would be useful to know for testing purposes

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the scrolldelay attribute to the MARQUEE tag. So an example of this would be:

```
Dim resulte As String = "<MARQUEE SCROLLDELAY=500>" & str & " " & example & "</MARQUEE>"
```